# Use texture as palette in OpenGL ES 2.0 shader

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, shader

I am using OpenGL ES 2.0 shaders to generate fractals. It has worked well, until I decided that black and white is not enough and I need a palette. I pass the palette as 1D texture to the shader, but all I get is black screen.

The shader is based on [this one](http://nuclear.mutantstargoat.com/articles/sdr_fract/#mbrot), with the texture passed being 2D (nx1), because of OpenGL ES 2.0 not allowing 1D textures, hence the pixel color is being got by

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D(palette, vec2((j == int(iterations) ? 0.0 : float(j)) / iterations, 0.5));
```

(I am not sure about the 0.5 here).

The relevant texture loading code:

```
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(colors, colors.length, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    int handle = ShaderUtils.loadTexture(bitmap);
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, handle);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(paletteHandle, handle);
```

[...]

```
public static int loadTexture(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    final int[] textureHandle = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);
    if (textureHandle[0] == 0)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error generating texture name.");
    }
    // Bind to the texture in OpenGL
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[0]);
    // Set filtering
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
            GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
            GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
    // Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    // Recycle the bitmap, since its data has been loaded into OpenGL.
    bitmap.recycle();

    return textureHandle[0];
}
```

Vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 vPosition;

void main() {
  gl_Position = vPosition;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D palette;
uniform float centerX;
uniform float centerY;
uniform float scale;
uniform float iterations;
uniform vec2 resolution;
#define maxiter 1024
void main() {
    vec2 center = vec2(centerX, centerY);
    vec2 coord = vec2(gl_FragCoord.x, gl_FragCoord.y) / resolution;
    vec2 c = (coord - center) / scale;
    int j = 0;
    vec2 z = c;
    for(int i = 0; i<maxiter; i++) {
        if (float(i) >= iterations) break;
        j++;
        float x = (z.x * z.x - z.y * z.y) + c.x;
        float y = (z.y * z.x + z.x * z.y) + c.y;

        if((x * x + y * y) > 4.0) break;
        z.x = x;
        z.y = y;
    }

    gl_FragColor = texture2D(palette, vec2((j == int(iterations) ? 0.0 : float(j)) / iterations, 0.5));
//    vec3 color = vec3(float(j)/float(iterations));
//    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

Problem is that this is very hard to debug. From inside the IDE I made sure that the bitmap contains proper data and there are no opengl errors in the logcat. The shader works without the texture, so it is probably the problem here. What could be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value which you have to set to the texture sampler uniform is **not** the "name" of the texture object, it has to be the index of the texture unit:

```
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, handle);

// this is wrong
//GLES20.glUniform1i(paletteHandle, handle);

GLES20.glUniform1i(paletteHandle, 0); // 0, because of GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0
```

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Compatibility Profile Specification; 7.10 Samplers; page 154](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.compatibility.pdf):

> Samplers are special uniforms used in the OpenGL Shading Language to identify
>   the texture object used for each texture lookup. The value of a sampler indicates the texture image unit being accessed. **Setting a sampler’s value to `i` selects texture image unit number `i`.**

Comment: Thanks so much! And kudos for spotting that right away